# blogspot.com List of all posts of the same tag

Tags: javascript, tags, blogger, posts, blogspot

I created a new page on my blog and I would like to add there a list of all posts which include the same tag. For example: the tag name is "game" and I am looking for an JavaScript which will list all posts with images that contain tag "game".

Here I have already a code that lists popular posts:

```
<div class="widget-slimecuty-popular-posts">
<ul id="popular-li-container" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXML(url) {
          var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {
              parseResponse(xmlRequest);
            }
          };
          xmlRequest.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlRequest.send();
        }
        function parseResponse(xml) {
          var txtData = xml.responseText;
          var parserDiv = document.createElement("div");
          parserDiv.innerHTML = txtData;
          var posts = parserDiv.getElementsByTagName("entry");
          for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var links = posts[i].getElementsByTagName("link");
            for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
              if (links[j].getAttribute("rel") == "alternate") {
                makeContainer(i);
                var title = links[j].getAttribute("title");
                var link = links[j].getAttribute("href");
                makeTitle(title, i);
                makeLink(link, i);
                var content = posts[i].getElementsByTagName("content");
                if (content.length == 0) break;
                var parserContentDiv = document.createElement("div");
                parserContentDiv.innerHTML = content[0].innerText;
                var imgs = parserContentDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
                if (imgs.length == 0) break;
                var imgurl = imgs[0].getAttribute("src");
                makeImage(imgurl, i);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        function makeContainer(num) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.style.padding = "0";
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          var table = document.createElement("table");
          table.style.width = "100%";
          var tr = document.createElement("tr");
          var td1 = document.createElement("td");
          td1.style.height = "72px";
          td1.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
          var td2 = document.createElement("td");
          td2.style.width = "100%";
          td2.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
          var a1 = document.createElement("a");
          a1.id = "popular-img-" + num;
          a1.href = "javascript: void(0)";
          a1.target = "_blank";
          var a2 = document.createElement("a");
          a2.id = "popular-title-" + num;
          a2.href = "javascript: void(0)";
          a2.target = "_blank";
          a2.style.fontSize = "15pt";
          td1.appendChild(a1);
          td2.appendChild(a2);
          tr.appendChild(td1);
          tr.appendChild(td2);
          table.appendChild(tr);
          div.appendChild(table);
          li.appendChild(div);
          document.getElementById("popular-li-container").appendChild(li);
        }
        function makeLink(link, num) {
          document.getElementById("popular-title-" + num).setAttribute("href", link);
          document.getElementById("popular-img-" + num).setAttribute("href", link);
        }
        function makeTitle(title, num) {
          document.getElementById("popular-title-" + num).innerText = title;
        }
        function makeImage(imgurl, num) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.style.border = "1px solid black";
          img.style.width = "72px";
          img.style.height = "72px";
          img.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgurl + "')";
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = imgurl;
          if (image.width > image.height)
            img.style.backgroundSize = "auto 100%";
          else
            img.style.backgroundSize = "100% auto";
          img.style.backgroundPosition = "50% 50%";
          img.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
          img.style.display = "inline-block";
          img.style.maxWidth = "none";
          document.getElementById("popular-img-" + num).appendChild(img);
        }
        function getPopularData() {
          var url = "/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published";
          loadXML(url);
        }
        window.onload = getPopularData;
    </script>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to change this code, however without programming experience in JavaScript with blogger I couldn't do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get blog posts for a specific label by XML feed (*as in your code*) use this url

`http://yourBlogUrl/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelName`

In Your code:

Replace `var url = "/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published";`

With `var url = "/feeds/posts/default/-/game";`

Note: Blogger labels are case sensitive, "game" different from "Game"

```
<div class="widget-slimecuty-popular-posts">
<ul id="popular-li-container" style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadXML(url) {
          var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {
              parseResponse(xmlRequest);
            }
          };
          xmlRequest.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlRequest.send();
        }
        function parseResponse(xml) {
          var txtData = xml.responseText;
          var parserDiv = document.createElement("div");
          parserDiv.innerHTML = txtData;
          var posts = parserDiv.getElementsByTagName("entry");
          for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var links = posts[i].getElementsByTagName("link");
            for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
              if (links[j].getAttribute("rel") == "alternate") {
                makeContainer(i);
                var title = links[j].getAttribute("title");
                var link = links[j].getAttribute("href");
                makeTitle(title, i);
                makeLink(link, i);
                var content = posts[i].getElementsByTagName("content");
                if (content.length == 0) break;
                var parserContentDiv = document.createElement("div");
                parserContentDiv.innerHTML = content[0].innerText;
                var imgs = parserContentDiv.getElementsByTagName("img");
                if (imgs.length == 0) break;
                var imgurl = imgs[0].getAttribute("src");
                makeImage(imgurl, i);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        function makeContainer(num) {
          var li = document.createElement("li");
          li.style.padding = "0";
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          var table = document.createElement("table");
          table.style.width = "100%";
          var tr = document.createElement("tr");
          var td1 = document.createElement("td");
          td1.style.height = "72px";
          td1.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
          var td2 = document.createElement("td");
          td2.style.width = "100%";
          td2.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
          var a1 = document.createElement("a");
          a1.id = "popular-img-" + num;
          a1.href = "javascript: void(0)";
          a1.target = "_blank";
          var a2 = document.createElement("a");
          a2.id = "popular-title-" + num;
          a2.href = "javascript: void(0)";
          a2.target = "_blank";
          a2.style.fontSize = "15pt";
          td1.appendChild(a1);
          td2.appendChild(a2);
          tr.appendChild(td1);
          tr.appendChild(td2);
          table.appendChild(tr);
          div.appendChild(table);
          li.appendChild(div);
          document.getElementById("popular-li-container").appendChild(li);
        }
        function makeLink(link, num) {
          document.getElementById("popular-title-" + num).setAttribute("href", link);
          document.getElementById("popular-img-" + num).setAttribute("href", link);
        }
        function makeTitle(title, num) {
          document.getElementById("popular-title-" + num).innerText = title;
        }
        function makeImage(imgurl, num) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.style.border = "1px solid black";
          img.style.width = "72px";
          img.style.height = "72px";
          img.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + imgurl + "')";
          var image = new Image();
          image.src = imgurl;
          if (image.width > image.height)
            img.style.backgroundSize = "auto 100%";
          else
            img.style.backgroundSize = "100% auto";
          img.style.backgroundPosition = "50% 50%";
          img.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
          img.style.display = "inline-block";
          img.style.maxWidth = "none";
          document.getElementById("popular-img-" + num).appendChild(img);
        }
        function getPopularData() {
          var url = "/feeds/posts/default/-/LabelName";
          loadXML(url);
        }
        window.onload = getPopularData;
    </script>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.